# Failed to shut down 1 bean with phase value 2147483647 within timeout of 30000: [org.springframework.jms.config.internalJmsListenerEndpointRegistry]

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I'm trying to shutdown a Java application which has 1 @JmsListener running.
It doesn't matter how long I wait, but it will never stop.

It eternally hangs on the doShutdown of DefaultMessageListenerContainer.

The threadump is

```
"DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1@6759" prio=5 tid=0x51 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1252)
      at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1326)
      at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.runHooks(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:107)
      at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks$1.run(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:46)
      at java.lang.Shutdown.runHooks(Shutdown.java:123)
      at java.lang.Shutdown.sequence(Shutdown.java:167)
      at java.lang.Shutdown.exit(Shutdown.java:212)
      - locked <0x20a> (a java.lang.Class)
      at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Runtime.java:109)
      at java.lang.System.exit(System.java:971)
      at my.package.MainApplication.stop(MainApplication.java:124)
```

I'm running Spring 4.3.19 and Spring Boot 1.5.16

Comment: There was a circular reference somewhere so that the bean was using itself during its shutdown procedure. Therefore, it could effectively never stop.

Comment: I have the same issue. It look like to be related when rabbit is there but not really

Comment: Have you tried by configuring a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor for the containerFactory